# Proper signal order to safely stop process

Tags: python, signals

I have a long-running Python process that I want to be able to terminate in the event it gets hung-up and stops reporting progress. But I want to signal it in a way that allows it to safely cleanup, in case it hasn't completely hung-up and there's still something running that can respond to signals gracefully. What's the best order of signals to send before outright killing it?

I'm currently doing something like:

```
def safe_kill(pid):
    for sig in [SIGTERM, SIGABRT, SIGINT, SIGKILL]:
         os.kill(pid, sig)
         time.sleep(1)
         if not pid_exists(pid):
             return
```

Is there a better order? I know SIGKILL bypasses the process entirely, but is there any significant difference between SIGTERM/SIGABRT/SIGINT or do they all have the same effect as far as Python is concerned?

Comment: You're going to need the process to register a signal handler if you want it to clean up after any of those signals. I don't think Python turns any of those into exceptions; it just stops.

Comment: I think the answer here depends on the python process that you're trying to gracefully kill -- Does it register any signal handlers?  If so, are they documented?  If it doesn't register any handlers, then I guess it doesn't really matter what you send first ;-)

Comment: @user2357112 -- SIGINT gets turned into `KeyboardInterrupt` IIRC ...

Comment: Right, forgot Ctrl-C was SIGINT. I thought it was SIGHUP or something.

Comment: If your Python process gets hung-up, shouldn't you fix the root cause for why it gets hung-up? :) I see people using daemons to restart such processes, when they should actually be putting in the effort to make it not get stuck at all. Who restarts the restarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the proper way for stopping a process is SIGTERM followed by SIGKILL after a small timeout.

I don't think that SIGINT and SIGABRT are necessary if that process handles signals in a standard way. SIGINT is usually handled the same way as SIGTERM and SIGABRT is usually used by process itself on abort() ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals)).

Anything more complex than a small script usually implements custom SIGTERM handling to shutdown gracefully (cleaning up all the resources, etc).

For example, take a look at Upstart. It is an init daemon - it starts and stops most of processes in Ubuntu and some other distributions. The default Upstart behavior for stopping a process is to send SIGTERM, wait 5 seconds and send SIGKILL (source - [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stopping-a-job)).

You probably should do some testing to determine the best timeout for your process.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register a signal handler, as you would do in C.

```
import signal
import sys

def clean_termination(signal):
    # perform your cleanup
    sys.exit(1)

# register the signal handler for the signals specified in the question
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, clean_termination)
signal.signal(signal.SIGABRT, clean_termination)
```

Note that Python maps the `SIGINT` signal to a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception, that you can catch with a regular `except` statement.